# Twilio Flex, Call Center Integrations / Streaming

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

**DISCLAIMER:** This question mentions Google Contact Center AI, which is currently in
*alpha*. DO NOT PROVIDE any references to CCAI api. The solution soley relies on Twilio Flex code & config.

Looking to use Flex as a call-center solution with Google Contact Center AI as a backing integration for "AI" capabilities. In order to do that, I need to understand the integration between the two products better... more specifically, the same integration in this demo: https://youtu.be/n5vMhntiReg?t=2332

Al Cook describes it as a simple integration and a matter of "looping the call to Google", but it does not seem so trivial.

A user and an operator utilize Flex for the phone call. Flex then *seems* to stream the call to CCAI as a separate process to which the transcription/NLP processing and knowledge base information is returned to Flex.

How exactly do we setup this type of integration in Flex?

Comment: I'll have a look around for some more detail, but I think this recorded webinar might have more details for you: https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/17272/343034/blueprint-to-ai-assisted-contact-centers-with-twilio-flex-and-google

Comment: @philnash thank you, any updates here?

Comment: Did you manage to watch the video?